# How to download and install unmet dependencies automatically

Tags: upgrade, software-installation, dependencies

Is there any method on command line or a software that will download and upgrade/install all unmet(missing or outdated) dependencies for a package automatically.
*There are some packages that have missing dependencies or some times the dependent package is of old version.*

Answer (score 1):

To upgrade all unmet dependencies of a package, you should install the package then run `apt-get -f install`.

Here's what you should generally do when you have unmet dependencies. First:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

The first command updates the package index, and the second upgrades any packages you have installed.

Then install your package using `dpkg -i <packagename>`. Then do:

```
sudo apt-get -f install 
sudp dpkg -a --configure
```

The first command goes out and looks for the dependencies and installs/upgrades them, and the second one continues the installation of your package (this is usually done by the first command anyways).

If you are getting errors, please copy and paste the exact commands you have used and the exact output you see. In your comment on the other answer, you mentioned you're not getting "unmet dependencies", so please clarify your question again and state exactly what you want to do.

Comment: please have a look to this question/i asked above question in different manner : http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/168568/52733

Comment: I still get the same results after following these steps: https://gist.github.com/adamjgrant/858093ee10852be6cefdabf873786352

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command in the terminal

`sudo apt-get -f install`

It will install any dependencies that are missing.

Comment: i am not getting 'unmet dependencies' error. so this method cant work